# How to check if a directory contains another directory in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, directory

I am looking for a simple (if possible) way in powershell to check if a directory contains at least 1 other directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dir = '.'  # specify the directory to investigate
$hasAnySubdir = (Get-ChildItem -Force -Directory $dir).Count -gt 0
```

`-Directory` (PSv3+) ensures that `Get-ChildItem` only enumerates sub-*directories*, and `-Force` ensures that even *hidden* subdirectories are included.

---

Note: If the directory contains an *unusually large number of subdirectories*, use the following instead:

```
$dir = '.'  # specify the directory to investigate
$hasAnySubdir = [bool] (Get-ChildItem -Force -Directory $dir | Select-Object -First 1)
```